# Какие есть сервисы интеграции рекламы в React Native Expo приложение, работающие в РФ?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, реклама, встроенная-реклама

Нужен сервис в котором можно зарегистрироваться в РФ, позволяющий интегрировать рекламу в React Native Expo приложение, желательно без какой либо проверки самого приложения.